# Mining-pool for MacOS?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, mac-osx

I would like to use a mining-pool like nanopool, but I have a Mac - what alternatives do I have?

Is my understanding right, that whenever I want to be part of a mining-pool I need a miner provided by the 'pool-creators' ?

AlethZero is just for solo-mining, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, MacOS can't keep up the difficulty by the pool without any eGPUs.
You can choose whatever pool you like, as long as they are paying/valid.